# How do i apply an element from javascript to multiple class names in the html

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to apply h2.appendChild(h2Text) to all three elements with the class name "flip-card-front". I'm trying to get h2 to display the word 'Accusation'. To make things easier i only added three cards in the html but for my project i'm trying to apply the h2 to 100 cards with the class name "flip-card-front"

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
    var h2 = document.createElement("h2");
var h2Text = document.createTextNode("Accusation ");

h2.appendChild(h2Text);
console.log(h2);
    document.body.appendChild(h2);

});
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script src="app.js" ></script>

</head> 

<body>
    <div class="flip-card">
        <div class="flip-card-inner">
            <div class="flip-card-front">
                <h2>Accusations </h2>
                <img
                    src='https://avataaars.io/?avatarStyle=Circle&topType=LongHairStraight&accessoriesType=Blank&hairColor=BrownDark&facialHairType=Blank&clotheType=BlazerShirt&eyeType=Default&eyebrowType=Default&mouthType=Default&skinColor=Light' />
            </div>
            <div class="flip-card-back">
                <h1>John Doe</h1>
                <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
                <p>We love that guy</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="flip-card">
        <div class="flip-card-inner">
            <div class="flip-card-front">
                <img
                    src='https://avataaars.io/?avatarStyle=Circle&topType=ShortHairTheCaesarSidePart&accessoriesType=Blank&hairColor=BrownDark&facialHairType=Blank&clotheType=BlazerShirt&eyeType=Default&eyebrowType=Default&mouthType=Default&skinColor=Light' />

            </div>
            <div class="flip-card-back">
                <h1>John Doe</h1>
                <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
                <p>We love that guy</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="flip-card">
        <div class="flip-card-inner">
            <div class="flip-card-front">
                <img
                    src='https://avataaars.io/?avatarStyle=Circle&topType=ShortHairShortFlat&accessoriesType=Kurt&hairColor=BrownDark&facialHairType=BeardMedium&facialHairColor=BrownDark&clotheType=ShirtVNeck&clotheColor=Blue03&eyeType=Default&eyebrowType=Default&mouthType=Default&skinColor=Light' />
            </div>
            <div class="flip-card-back">
                <h1>John Doe</h1>
                <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
                <p>We love that guy</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const front = document.getElementsByClassName("flip-card-front");
let header = document.createElement("h2");
header.innerHTML = "Accusation";
front.append(header);
```

ADDED:

```js
const cards = document.getElementById("cards");

function addTitleToCards() {
  for (let i = 0; i < cards.children.length; i++) {
    const card = cards.children[i]
    let header = document.createElement("h2")
    header.innerHTML = "Accusations"
    card.prepend(header)
  }
}

addTitleToCards()
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Cards</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="cards">
    <div class="flip-card">
      <img src='https://avataaars.io/?avatarStyle=Circle&topType=LongHairStraight&accessoriesType=Blank&hairColor=BrownDark&facialHairType=Blank&clotheType=BlazerShirt&eyeType=Default&eyebrowType=Default&mouthType=Default&skinColor=Light' />
      <h3>John Doe</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="flip-card">
      <img src='https://avataaars.io/?avatarStyle=Circle&topType=ShortHairTheCaesarSidePart&accessoriesType=Blank&hairColor=BrownDark&facialHairType=Blank&clotheType=BlazerShirt&eyeType=Default&eyebrowType=Default&mouthType=Default&skinColor=Light' />
      <h3>John Doe</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="flip-card">
      <img src='https://avataaars.io/?avatarStyle=Circle&topType=ShortHairShortFlat&accessoriesType=Kurt&hairColor=BrownDark&facialHairType=BeardMedium&facialHairColor=BrownDark&clotheType=ShirtVNeck&clotheColor=Blue03&eyeType=Default&eyebrowType=Default&mouthType=Default&skinColor=Light'
      />
      <h3>John Doe</h3>
    </div>
  </div>

  <body>

</html>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this will work because you only ever want to append children to a single node/element
getElementsByClassName returns a list of nodes
regardless of whether there's only one with that class name or not
you can generally tell if it has Elements in the name it'll return a list instead of a single one

Comment: True, what I suggested was how you would generally add elements to parent nodes. I've added a simplified code snippet for adding an element to multiple cards.